# Increase in HBASE DB Size after test run

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cluster-computing, hdfs

I was using HDFS+HBASE. I have created a database and ran a test for 2 hours. I want to check the increase in size of the database after test run.
I have tried to take readings using:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -report and
hadoop fs -dus /hbase.
```

Also tried to check the disk size using

```
du -sk /HADOOP.
```

Observation is after the test is run, the size shows decreased instead of increasing.

Versions being used : Hadoop 1.0.0, HBase 0.90.5 , ZooKeeper 3.3.4.
Compression on Column family is NONE.

Please help in getting the correct process to calculate the increase in DB size due to test.

Comment: what kind of test you run? are you sure, you don't truncate table between runs? how many data was written?

Comment: Its a Load Test. No Table Truncate is done between runs. Data written was ~ 650K Transactions/hr.

Comment: are you sure you don't run hbase in standalone mode? (because it is quite impossible to don't see any activity, especialy if we take into account, that hbase only appends data)

Comment: Its not Standalone. It's Clustered Environment. With 3 Data nodes.

Comment: I can suggest only one scenario: you put the same data into hbase and compaction accours. If you table created with versions=1, second copy of data was eliminated (if it was not random of course).

Comment: in short: i have only two versions: you look at wrong place or you data was garbage collected due of multiple versions for each keys

Answer (score 0):

Lakshmi, 650K is nothing for HBase / Hadoop. Default start block size is 128M (if I did not missed some major change) so you should not see anything significant after table creation. Actually your tables (HStore files) should be located under `/hbase/<table-name>` and region content is under `/hbase/<table-name>/<region>` (you can check regions info through HBase web UI).

If you really need to check something, load at least more than 128M of data. I usually do at least 4G DB to test regions allocation. Current default (starting from HBase 0.94) region splitting policy splits region starting from filled first 128M and then it happens more and more rarely.